Embedding Svelte 5 inside PHP (Imperative component API)
I'm trying to use Svelte 5 and SvelteKit inside PHP.
I don't understand how to use the Imperative component API (https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte/imperative-component-api). Where do I put the following code? Do I put it in src/routes/main.js?
import { mount } from 'svelte';
import App from './App.svelte';

const app = mount(App, {
    target: document.querySelector('#app'),
    props: { some: 'property' }
});

If I use vite build -w to build the project, what is the path of the built JavaScript to put inside the PHP?
<body>
  <h1>
    <?php echo "Hello, $user"; ?>
  </h1>

  <div id="app">
  </div>

  <script src="/path/build/what-is-the-name-of-the-js-file-for-here.js"></script>
</body>

What do I set src/routes/+layout.js to? My assumption is that I should first try making an SPA (https://svelte.dev/docs/kit/single-page-apps) with the following for src/routes/+layout.js:
export const ssr = false;

I made a file with the JavaScript from the Imperative component API, but I don't see it in build/.

tldr; Use @sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte without SvelteKit.

SvelteKit and the static adapter are not really compatible with custom backends that serve their own generated HTML. The output of a SvelteKit application is HTML, JS & CSS, so without the HTML part, the main entry point is missing.
You could potentially write your own adapter that outputs PHP which then can be processed by the backend and served. Alternatively you could create a component library, compile that down to JS/CSS via a separate build process and just link those files (you will lose pretty much all of the SvelteKit features like routing, though).

Ah, yes, I now understand that you can use Svelte with Vite without SvelteKit. Thanks!
